# Strange behaviour sending data with PHP JSON encode to jQuery getJSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am sending data from PHP to jQuery. Everything works fine except I want to sent the total rows from the DB.

I have stripped a lot of other things to put onlu the essential problem.

PHP code:

```
header('Content-type: text/json');
header('Content-type: application/json');
$rows = array with the data; That is working fine

$total=mysql_num_rows($RSList);
$total_data=array("total"=>$total);
array_push($data,$total_data,$rows); 
echo json_encode($data);
```

jQuery code:

```
$.getJSON("..url..", function( data ) {
  var data_array = eval(data);
  $.each(data_array[0], function(i, item ) {
    console.log(item)
  });
});
```

The result showing in the browser is:

```
[{"total":532},[{"product_id":"1",.... }]]
```

532 is the correct value from the `mysql_num_rows()`

Console:
An empty string

I tried the following:

If I set the value manually of total in PHP:

```
$total=100;
```

The result showing in the browser is:

```
[{"total":100},[{"product_id":"1",.... }]]
```

Console of java:
100

If I convert the value in string in PHP:

```
$total="(".$totalRows_RSList.")";
```

The result showing in the browser is:

```
[{"total":"(532)"},[{"product_id":"1",.... }]]
```

Console:
()

I have also tried `intval`, `number_format` and `strval` with no success.

Very, very strange or ?

Update:
I have modified as suggested the code and still the same problem:

PHP:

```
echo json_encode(array('total' => $total, 'rows' => $rows));
```

javscript:

```
$.getJSON( "..url..", function( data ) {
    console.log( data )
    $.each( data.rows, function(i, item ) {...}
})
```

Browser:

```
{"total":532,"rows":[{"product_id":"567",...}]}
```

Console:

```
Object { rows=[99], total=""}
```

Comment: It will look and read better if you'd use keys in the arrays. `json_encode(array('total' => $total, 'rows' => $rows));` and `$.each(data.rows, ...)`

Comment: I have changed it, still the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This answer explains what is wrong with your code. Learn from it, then look at @ojovirtual's answer which shows what I think is the best way for you to accomplish what you were intending to do in the first place. **End Note**

Remove the `eval` statement from your code. jQuery will have already parsed the incoming JSON (if it is valid) and your success function will receive your array as the `data` param. Just use that `data` param instead of `data_array`.

```
$.getJSON('..url..', function (data) {
    // if your PHP is sending proper JSON in the format you describe, `data` is now
    // an array containing two items. The first (`data[0]`) is an object which has
    // one property, `total`. The second (`data[1]`) is your array of row data, each
    // of which is an object.

    // your code in modified form, though I don't understand why you would use `each`
    $.each(data[0], function (i, item) {
        console.log(item);
    });

    // just use:
    console.log(data[0].total);
});
```

Be sure to read the comments in the above code.

Comment: The problem must be from the mysql_num_rows($RSList), because when I set the value total=99, it is working and the strangest thing is that in th browser the value is fine [{"total":532},[{"product_id":"1",.... }]]

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass the total rows, just get the length of the parsed JSON object.

jQuery code:

```
$.getJSON('...url...', function(data){
    console.log(data.length);
}
```

PHP Code:

```
header('Content-type: text/json');
header('Content-type: application/json');
$rows = array_with_the_data; //That is working fine
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: This is a very good point. The OP should use my answer to understand why his own code doesn't work, and should use this answer as the way he moves forward to accomplish his goal.

Comment: Yes, I could do this, but I want to pass more data as the pages and I get the same problem with data from the my_sql query.